# Check whether pdf attachement does'nt exsist in gmail python using imap

Tags: python, gmail, imap

I am able to search for a mail based on parameters and if a attachment exist do the relevant logic ,
However if search is successful and attachment doesn't exists i am unable to track it.
any suggestions would be appreciated.
code as following,

```
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
       continue
    if (part.get('Content-Disposition')) is None:
      continue
    filename = part.get_filename()
    if bool(filename):
       print('have attachment')
       # call relevant function
       # This works

    else:  
      print('no attachment')
     #call relevant function
     # This doesn't work
```

Comment: Do you really expect anyone to understand the problem with that lack of detail?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(all=True)):
        print(msg.date, msg.subject)
        if any(att.filename.lower().endswith('.pdf') for att in msg.attachments):
            print('- has pdf')
        else:
            print('- no pdf')
```

*I am lib author

Do not be so lazy, use search